# Why can't some skins be purchased in the shop?

Tags: league-of-legends

I saw that many skins can't be found or bought in *League of Legends*' shop. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some skins were available only in Collector's Edition:

- Black Alistar
- Human Ryze

Other skins were available only in some Special Events:

- Riot Squad Singed
- PAX Jax
- PAX Twisted Fate
- King Rammus
- UFO Corki
- Victorious Jarvan
- Judgement Kayle

Finally some skins are now known as Legacy, they were available in store but are now not purchasable anymore.

The list is quite long and is maintained here on [League of Legends Wikia](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Champion_skin).

Answer (score 9):

Some skins were for events, such as the Winter Olympic skins that were only purchasable during the 2010 Winter Olympics.  Others were given for helping Riot out, such as "King Rammus," which was given to beta testers.  I don't have a complete list, but I believe that covers most of the unbuyable skins.

Comment: There are also US only skins, such as Pax Jax. Rioted Singed was EU only and only avaliable through attending events, although they did have it on sale for a short period. There are also seasonal skins that you won't be able to get hold of now, including the Halloween skins, i.e. Lollipoppy. One of the olympic skins included Union Jack fiddlesticks.

Comment: Additionally some skins portrait selections are released way before they are even available. Lollipoppy and Sailor Gangplank for example had their portrait selection in the skins section but were not available to purchase for months. I don't know the rhyme or reasoning behind these ones.

Answer (score 0):

Some skins can only be bought in the duration of an event, e.g. Halloween, or Christmas. Also, some skins can be not purchased but won through referrals like Grey Warwick.