# Rare/Promotional Skins

Tags: league-of-legends

Is there a list somewhere of all skins that can be acquired through promotions or are given out rarely? I have looked online but cannot seem to find a full list.

Example, PAX Sivir which can only be used on NA Servers and was handed out at a event.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why can't some skins be purchased in the shop?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/14076/why-cant-some-skins-be-purchased-in-the-shop)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Skins that cannot be in mystery gifts?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/169243/skins-that-cannot-be-in-mystery-gifts). This question has a more up-to-date answer as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Trendee, I'll try to list all of the rare and promotional skins.
Source - [All Champion Skins](http://eune.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=425912)

**---- Two skins you can get fairly easily right now:**

- Unchained Alistar - Subscribe to Riot Games' YouTube channel
- Riot Girl Tristana - "Like" on Facebook

*Note that I will not list most of the legacy skins; However, I will list legacy skins that were given out during promotions.

- All Star Akali - 975 RP (Limited - Football World Cup in RPA 2010)
- Black Alistar - (Limited - digital pre-order)
- Vancouver Amumu - (Limited - Winter Olympics in Vancouver 2010)
- Regifted Amumu - 520 RP (Limited - Snowdown 2010)
- Team Spirit Anivia - (Limited - Winter Olympics in Vancouver 2010)
- Goth Annie - Included in Digital Collector's Pack (3900 RP)
- FrankenTibbers Annie - 975 RP (Limited - Harrowing 2011)
- Rusty Blitzcrank - (Limited - discontinued 17.01.2010)
- Goalkeeper Blitzcrank - 520 RP (Limited - Football World Cup in RPA 2010)
- Definitely Not Blitzcrank - 520 RP (Limited - Harrowing 2011)
- Arctic Warfare Caitlyn - 975 RP or PC Gamer Promo, North America (If you didn't get this from the promotion, you can still buy it)
- Nightmare Cho'Gath - 520 RP (Legacy ; Used to be free through partnership with Alienware)
- UFO Corki - Free for accounts created before 14.01.2010 (Limited)
- Ice Toboggan Corki - (Limited - Winter Olympics in Vancouver 2010)
- Mundo Mundo - 975 RP (Limited - Harrowing 2010)
- Striker Ezreal - 520 RP (Limited - Football World Cup in RPA 2010)
- Union Jack Fiddlesticks - (Limited - Winter Olympics in Vancouver 2010)
- Pumpkinhead Fiddlesticks - 520 RP (Limited - Harrowing 2010)
- Toy Soldier Gangplank - 975 RP (Limited - Snowdown 2011)
- Santa Gragas - 975 RP (Limited - Snowdown 2010)
- Snowmedinger - 975 RP (Limited - Snowdown 2011)
- Victorious Jarvan IV - Limited: Gold or Platinum medal in Season 1
- The Mighty Jax - (Limited - Winter Olympics in Vancouver 2010)
- PAX Jax** - Limited: Pax 2010 or Pax East 2011
- Festival Kassadin - (Limited - Winter Olympics in Vancouver 2010)
- Red Card Katarina - 975 RP (Limited - Football World Cup in RPA 2010)
- Kitty Cat Katarina - 975 RP (Limited - Harrowing 2010)
- Silver Kayle - Collector's Edition
- Judgement Kayle - Limited: 10 matched games in Season 1
- Reindeer Kog'maw - 975 RP (Limited - Snowdown 2010)
- Festive Maokai - 975 RP (Limited - Snowdown 2011)
- Candy Cane Miss Fortune - 975 RP (Limited - Snowdown 2010)
- K-9 Riot Nasus - Meet Rioter personally
- Snow Bunny Nidalee - (Limited - Snowdown 2009)
- Bewitching Nidalee - 975 RP (Limited - Harrowing 2011)
- Haunting Nocturne - 520 RP (Limited - Harrowing 2011)
- Workshop Nunu - (Limited - Snowdown 2009)
- Lollipoppy Poppy - 975 RP (Limited - Harrowing 2010)
- Ragdoll Poppy - 975 RP (Limited - Snowdown 2010)
- King Rammus - Limited: Closed Beta Testers
- Human Ryze - (Limited - Amazon/Gamestop Pre-order)
- Champion Ryze - Win certain LoL Events
- Zombie Ryze - 975 RP (Limited - Harrowing 2010)
- Nutcracko - 975 RP (Limited - Snowdown 2010)
- Riot Squad Singed - Limited: Meet Rioter personally (before GamesCom 2011)
- Huntress Sivir - Direct 2 Drive or Gamer's Choice Pack
- PAX Sivir* - Limited: PAX Prime 2011 Goodie Bags
- Silent Night Sona - 520 RP (Limited - Snowdown 2010)
- Happy Elf Teemo - (Limited - Snowdown 2009)
- Earnest Elf Tristana - (Limited - Snowdown 2009)
- Viking Tryndamere - 975 RP or promotion code from Dreamhack Summer 2011
- PAX Twisted Fate - Limited: PAX 2009
- Whistler Village Twitch - (Limited - Winter Olympics in Vancouver 2010))
- Medieval Twitch - 50 referred friends with RaF 2.0 (350 with RaF 1.0)
- Curling Veigar - (Limited - Winter Olympics in Vancouver 2010)
- Nosferatu Vladimir - 975 RP (Limited - Harrowing 2010)
- Grey Warwick - 25 reffered friends with RaF 2.0 (50 with RaF 1.0)
- Urf the Manatee - 5000 RP (99% sales during first week) (Limited - April's Fool 2010)
- Winger Hussar Xin Zhao - 975 RP or help with bug testing Polish client version
- Old St. Zilean - (Limited - (23.12.2009 - 27.12.2009))

I have been to PAX East 2012 this year, and have gathered some knowledge about the PAX skins.

*PAX Sivir could be obtained @Riot Games Booth at PAX East 2012.
**PAX Jax was difficult to obtain at PAX East 2012, but was still available then. I had to win it from this "Spin to Win" wheel of fortune type game there.

Comment: This is quite the wall of text, but unfortunately, it's going to be hard to keep up to date.

Comment: Well, as long as I'm an active user on this site, it won't be too hard to keep up with. Other users can edit this, too.

Comment: Can you move the 'skins you can get' to the top; its hard to find buried right at the bottom and I found it more useful than the others (that are unobtainable).

Comment: @Alok I've moved them to the top.

Comment: You left out Sonoran Kog'Maw

Comment: Thanks! I'd already upvoted the post so you just get a ty for the update ;). Btw, I'll delete both comments later to reduce clutter.

Answer (score 4):

The official League of Legends forums has a stickied thread with a detailed listing of all champion skins.

[Link Here](http://eune.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=425912)

On this list, you want to look for skins that are denoted as either *Limited* or *Legacy*.

*Limited* skins are those that were only available in certain events / time periods, and include things like PAX Sivir and the holiday skins (Harrowing '10 / '11).

*Legacy* skins are skins that were formerly available for purchase, but have been retired from the store. They include some of the earliest skins (little more than color changes) that have been determined to no longer meet Riot quality standards. There has been some talk of making them available again in limited "runs", but they will never again be available in the store full time. Going forward, all new holiday skins will be *Legacy* skins, rather than *limited* skins.

Comment: Is there not a list just for promo/rare codes? It would take a while to sift out the ones i need from the list.

Answer (score 1):

The League of Legends wiki maintains a [list of all skins](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Champion_skin), with categories for different sets of promo / limited run skins.  It may be helpful for you.