# Skins that cannot be in mystery gifts?

Tags: league-of-legends

Yesterday I had a discussion with some of my friends while playing league. It was about the contents of the mystery gifts and while I said there are restrictions, they were convinced that you can get absolutely every skin from a gift (including victorious, and really old ones).

Now while I'm pretty sure that there are restrictions (Triumphant ryze for example), I'm not really sure on which skins they affect.

What about the victorious, riot, legacy, pax and completely removed skins (Rusty BC, Black Ali, Urf WW)? Can you get those with a mistery gift or is it impossible to get those right now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In League of Legends [FAQ](http://promo.euw.leagueoflegends.com/en/lunar-revel-2014/index-mobile.html) site, for `"What skins are eligible for Mystery Gifting?"` it is said that:

> Any skin for any Champion that your friend owns is eligible as a
>   Mystery Skin, as long as your friend doesn’t already own the skin and
>   it’s currently worth 520 RP or higher and available in the store. This
>   includes Legendary and even Ultimate skins! All Legacy skins will also
>   be obtainable as a Mystery Skin **EXCEPT** Achievement skins, Collector’s
>   Edition skins, PAX skins, Rusty Blitzcrank, Urf the Manatee,
>   Championship Riven and Riot Squad Singed.
>
> There are also some Legacy skins not for sale in the store that will
>   be obtainable as a Mystery Skin. For a complete list of all the
>   different skin types, check out our Guide to Champion Skin Types.

You can see the mentioned skins in the following link: [Guide to Champion Skin Types](https://support.leagueoflegends.com/entries/22578914-Guide-to-Champion-Skin-Types)

**List of Skins which are not obtainable according to the source:**

**Achievement Skins**

*Victorious Skins* (obtained by reaching Gold or higher in a Ranked season)

- Victorious Jarvan IV (Season 1)
- Victorious Janna (Season 2)
- Victorious Elise (Season 3)
- Victorious Morgana (Season 4)
- Victorious Sivir (Season 5)
- Victorious Maokai (Season 6)

*Refer-A-Friend* (RAF)

- Grey Warwick (refer 3 friends who reach level 10 or higher)
- Medieval Twitch (refer 5 friends who reach level 10 or higher)

> The Refer-a-Friend program has been retired, so these skins are currently unavailable. We may release them as rewards for social initiatives in the future, so keep an eye out!

*Other*

- Triumphant Ryze (win an official League of Legends tournament)
- Riot Girl Tristana (become a fan on the official League of Legends
  Facebook page)
- Unchained Alistar (subscribe to the officialLeague of Legends YouTube
  channel)
- King Rammus (awarded to players who participated in Closed Beta)
- Judgement Kayle (awarded to players who played at least 10 matchmade
  games in Season 1)
- UFO Corki (awarded to players for voting in the Reader's Choice
  Awards 2009)

**Collector Edition Skins**

- Goth Annie (Digital Collector's Edition)
- Black Alistar (Digital Collector's Edition - Preorder)
- Silver Kayle (Retail Collector's Edition)
- Human Ryze (Retail Collector's Edition - Preorder)

**PAX Skins**

- PAX Twisted Fate (PAX 2009)
- PAX Jax (PAX East/Prime 2010 & PAX East 2011)
- PAX Sivir (PAX Prime 2011)

**Others Mentioned**

- Rusty Blitzcrank
- Urf the Manatee
- Championship Riven
- Riot Squad Singed

Comment: Does it mean, if I create a new account, buy a legendary skin. Which then would be the only skin I own, then give mystery gift to friends, they would receive it? So we could save like 1500 RP each time I do that?